# Bootstrap v3, Reverse Stacking Order of Full-Width Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to reverse the order of full width columns in Bootstrap v3? For example...

-xs (both A and B are col-xs-12)

[ A ]

[ B ]

-sm (both A and B are col-sm-12)

[ B ]

[ A ]

I know that I could use hide/show techniques, but I want to avoid duplicate content because both A and B have a lot of dynamically generated content, and duplicating that content will slow the page down quite a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Bootstraps  `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` classes.

More on this, here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/PPyaJQ)

For full width column example using push/pull helper classes please see this JS bin:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/gazipa/2/edit?html,css,output

You can also use CSS transform to change it's ordering at a viewport breakpoint:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.reorder-xs {
    /*bring your own prefixes*/
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    direction: rtl; /* Fix the horizontal alignment */
  }

  .row.reorder-xs > [class*="col-"] {
    /*bring your own prefixes*/
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    direction: ltr; /* Fix the horizontal alignment */
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/gazipa/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Tried this, but if the columns are full width (in your example, if both are col-md-12) I don't believe push/pull work.

Comment: Again, the example you posted is not full width. "col-sm-6" is a column that is 1/2 the container width, not full (100%) width. I am looking to reverse the order of full-width columns, for example if both divs have: .col-xs-12 .col-sm-12, I want the stacking order to be opposite in -sm and -xs

Comment: Works great, thanks. Might want to mention the browser specific transforms (    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);)

Answer (score 1):

**2018 Update Bootstrap 4**

In Bootstrap 4, you can change the order of full-width (12 unit) columns using the flexbox ordering classes. For example,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 order-sm-1 order-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-1">2 (first on xs)</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VUjKsM3cUD

Answer (score 0):

For those on Bootstrap 3, just add a flexbox wrapper.  Then you can add flex-direction with column reverse.  The code would look something like this (assume mobile first)...

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="flex-switch">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            This is a column
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            This is a column
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-switch {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;

    @include sm-min {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```